# How to detect if any app is launched using swift

Tags: ios, authentication, swift4

If user launches any application in the device, how can I detect using swift? I am new to iOS development. Any help is appreciated.

Actually I want to implement authorization when an app is opened.

Thanks

Comment: You want to detect when ***your*** app is opened? Or are you trying to write an app that can detect when ***some other*** app is opened?

Comment: @DonMag , Trying to write an app that can detect when some other app is opened

Comment: OK - you cannot do that. For security purposes, apps run in a "sandbox" and can have only indirect communication with other apps.

Comment: Actually I want to write an app which authorizes when user opens some other app, how can I achieve this?

Comment: You cannot do that. Your app does *not* have access to the system in that way. If you are talking about perhaps an in-house enterprise environment, where all the "other apps" are also developed by you, you *possibly* could restrict your "other apps" to only run when launched from your "authorization" app. But that doesn't sound like what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can't to listen native secured processes on iOS. And this is good for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Each and every app installed on iOS has a private area known as "SandBox" means, no other apps have any control over each other.

You can read more about SandBox [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AboutAppSandbox/AboutAppSandbox.html).